# Diamond Chat Aware - Helping you be aware of your audience when moving from private to public chat rooms

Tags: script, chat

[image: Chat Diamond Aware Thumbnail]

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Chat with watermark in textbox]

### About

While very subtle, in the above screenshot, you see a diamond watermark in the textbox.  As someone who spends time in private rooms, mostly for moderation purposes, I find it's easy to sometimes forget where I am. I've also heard others mention this, so I wrote a browser-add on for both Firefox and Chrome, which adds a watermark to all private chat rooms.

#### License

This is licensed under the open source MIT License.

---

### Download and Installation

#### Firefox

To install in Firefox, visit the [Mozilla Add-ons page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/diamondchat/).

#### Chrome/Chromium

To install in Chrome, visit the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/diamond-chat-aware/idcnhgnojajmgfngnkfalkadpfpkacnk?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

#### Userscript

This can also be installed as a userscript. For more information, see the [instructions on installing as a userscript](https://github.com/jamesmortensen/diamond-chat-aware#userscript).

---

### Platform

This extension runs on Mac OS, Windows, and Linux, in both Firefox and Chrome browsers. It may run in other browsers that support userscripts, but I have not personally tested this.

### Contact

I created this extension, and it was conceptualized by [Monica Cellio](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/325/monica-cellio), [jmac](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/7945/jmac), and [enderland](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/2322/enderland).  To report issues, please use the [issue tracker](https://github.com/jamesmortensen/diamond-chat-aware/issues). I can also be found in chat for questions. You can also leave a comment here.

### Code

To build this extension, I used [OpenForge](https://github.com/trigger-corp/browser-extensions), an open source framework for building cross-browser extensions from one single codebase. The extension consists of mostly JavaScript, as well as some CSS.

The userscript, on the other hand, doesn't use any frameworks or third-party libraries.  Anyone new to userscripts may find it useful as a learning tool.

The code is open sourced in [the Diamond Chat Aware GitHub repository](https://github.com/jamesmortensen/diamond-chat-aware). If you want to learn more, see the code, or contribute pull requests.

Comment: Nice script, thanks for the share!  It might bear mentioning that the http should be changed for https now.